# HTML Video set by javascript doesn't play on iOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, html5-video

I'm having issues with the HTMl5 Video Player. I'm setting the video src with a javascript script but it doesn't play on any iOS Device. It works on macOS and any other device though.
Any help?

Here's a snippet of my HTML:

```
<video class="img-fluid" id="postvideo" playsinline controls autoplay loop controlsList="nodownload">
</video>
```

And Javascript:

```
          isSupp = vid.canPlayType("video/mp4");
  if (isSupp == "") {
         vid.src = video;
  } else {
   vid.src = video;
  }
    vid.type = 
  vid.load();
```

As you can see I already tried playsinline.

Answer (score 0):

Does the video play on the iOS device without the Javascript?